# How much ES6 classes differ from ES5 style?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I'm that kind of a person who needs to know everything in depth... So, I've been going through many taught subjects and I set my foot into depths of Prototype-inheritance.
I have a clear vision of how it works in ES5 (Every function has this special prototype property, which points to an object on which it is based on. This object has .constructor property, which points back to the function etc.).

So, now let's see ES5 example:

```
function Bunny(name) {
    this.name = name
}

Bunny.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log('Im',this.name)
}
```

This one is pretty clear: function Bunny gets argument `name` which's going to be assign to a new object.

Next line adds function to the function's prototype, which's going to return current name.

Let's see ES6 class now:

```
class Fox{
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    sayName() {
        console.log('Im', this.name)
    }
}
```

Same stuff here: `Constructor` here is like our Bunny function. But `sayName` in fox is not the same as `sayName` in Bunny.
Let's create the instances:

```
let bunny = new Bunny('Henry');
let fox = new Fox('Jerry');
```

And now, check their prototypes:

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(bunny))
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(fox))
```

What do we get?

```
//using repl.it - ES6
{ sayName: [Function] }
{}
```

Why is that?

I thought it might be because we set function `sayName` on Bunny's prototype directly. So I've changed it to this:

```
function Bunny(name) {
    this.name = name

    //Warning - Bad practice ahead! 
    this.sayName = function() {
        console.log('Im',this.name)
    }
}
```

Result:

```
//using repl.it - ES6
{}
{}
```

That would have sense, if not this:

```
console.log(bunny.hasOwnProperty('sayName'))
console.log(fox.hasOwnProperty('sayName'))
```

Which means, `fox` does not own `sayName` on him, either prototype shows it has it. Am I missing something here? Why They are different?

Comment: Why is the second example bad practice?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because it creates a new function for each instance.

Comment: Never use `console.log` to inspect an object. Use `console.dir`.

Comment: Never heard this one, sounds interesting - why so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ES6 classes all methods are non-enumerable, so you when you log a prototype of an instance of an ES6 class, you get something that looks like an empty object.

See this example:

```js
const obj = new (class {method() {}});

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)); // {}
console.log(typeof Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).method); // function
```

In ES5 you define a method by assigning it to a property of the class prototype, which makes it enumerable. If you wanted to achieve the same effect as with ES6 classes, you could use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) instead:

```js
const TestClass = function TestClass() {};
Object.defineProperty(TestClass.prototype, 'method', {
  value: function() {},
  writable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true,
});
const obj = new TestClass();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)); // {}
console.log(typeof Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).method); // function
```

---

And `fox.hasOwnProperty('sayName')` returns `false` because `hasOwnProperty()` checks only for own properties, and `sayName` is in the prototype chain. If you want to check for properties in the prototype chain too, you can use the `in` operator: `'sayName' in fox` returns `true`.

---

See also [Enumerability and ownership of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) on MDN.

Comment: Ah, that's what I've missed! Nice One!
Also, I went ahead and paste my code into babel transpiler -> got the code in ES5. 
There is a for loop which goes through all properties in constructor and check if they are enumerable -> `methods` are not!  Checking it with `.propertyIsEnumerable` result in false.  
Also, I have checked `.hasOwnProperty` on both `fox` and `fox.prototype` with same result. But I didn't mention it in my question, my bad.